# Const still allowing changes under operator function c++

Tags: c++, class, constants

I have the following code:

```
StringC StringC::operator+(const StringC& other) const
{
    strcat(ps,other.ps);
    return ps;
};
```

with the relevant header as follows:

```
class StringC {
private:
    char* ps;
public:
    StringC(char const *);
    StringC& operator=(const StringC&);
    StringC operator+(const StringC& other) const;
    void Print();
```

It is my understanding that the use of `const` in the `operator+` function should stop me being able to change `ps` and `other` however I am able to change both of them still.

I have tried the following:

```
void Class1::Method1() const
{
    Variable = Variable + 1;
};

void Class1::Method1(const int v)
{
    v = 0;
    Variable = v + 1;
};
```

And this errors as expected, I assume I am missing something in my use of const, but would have expected the first code to error when using `strcat`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> It is my understanding that the use of `const` in the `operator+` function should stop me being able to change `ps` and `other` however I am able to change both of them still.

And this is correct.  You cannot change `ps` or `other.ps`, however, that is not what you are doing.  What you are doing is changing the contents of what `ps` points to, which is not const.

So, in `operator+` the type of `ps` is `char * const` (constant pointer to a char) and not `const char *` (pointer to a constant char)

Comment: so the const here should be preventing me from changing what ps points to? but when I add `*ps = '\0';` I get no error?

Comment: @stuart194 Yes, it is stopping you from changing the address that `ps` holds.  If you try `ps = nullptr` you will get an error.  `*ps = '\0'` doesn't change what the pointer points to.  It changes the thing the pointer points to.

Comment: So basically using const in these situations basically stops you from accidently moving where the point is pointing?

Comment: @stuart194 -- always keep in mind that the **pointer** is not the same thing as **what it's pointing at**. `const char*` is a modifiable pointer that points at an unmodifiable `char`; `char *const` is an umodifiable pointer that points at a modifiable `char`.

Comment: @stuart194 It stops you from changing what the pointer points to, you cannot give it a different address to point to.